# Como cambiar entre frames dentro de la misma venta

Tags: python

Ahora si, como estan? les comento que estoy trabajando  en Python sobre este programa de calculo aeronautico, el mismo tendra muchas iteraciones y procesos que se comunican entre si, al menos eso quiero lograr, debo reconocer que el programa es mucho mas amplio de lo que esta en el codigo, y tiene mas botones en menu y mas definiciones, pero lo depure lo mas que pude con fines de practicidad. mi duda es, como pueden ver a continuacion, asi se verian la interfaz grafica, ahora....

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que yo deseo hacer es que segun el menu que selecciono me cambien los frames dentro de la ventana, no se mucho al respecto no tengo gran experiencia ni en Python ni en programacion pero he visto algo asi como que tengo que empacketar las frames, y ocultarlas o mandarlas al frente, pero resulta que tratando de adquirir experiencia con distintos repositorios, no logro aplicar los ejercicios existentes a lo que yo necesito, sea por que los que ya tienen configurado que cambie la frame desde un boton, no me deja agregar la barra de menu, o cosas semejantes, entiendo que podria separar por clases o instanciarlas desde otra ventana que nativamente tenga los menu, y simplemente inserto adentro el contenido, la realidad es que como decia no tengo experiencia y voy aprendiendo en la medida que voy haciendo, ojala alguien me pueda ayuda

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import subprocess


# DEFINO LAS LLAMADAS A LAS FUNCIONES   
def inst():
    subprocess.call(["python", "instrucciones.py"])    
# CREO VENTANA PRINCIPAL
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Software de calculo y diseño aerodinamico")
root.geometry("800x600+0+0")
root.config(background="gray17")
# CREO EL MENU DE LA VENTANA
menu = tk.Menu(root, background="gray17")
# CREO LAS OPCIONES PRINCIPALES DEL MENU
menu_archivo = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=0, background='black', foreground='white', activeforeground='black', activebackground='gray52')
menu_var = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=0, background='black', foreground='white', activeforeground='black', activebackground='gray52')
menu_dsg = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=0, background='black', foreground='white', activeforeground='black', activebackground='gray52')
menu_cal = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=0, background='black', foreground='white', activeforeground='black', activebackground='gray52')
menu_cfg = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=0, background='black', foreground='white', activeforeground='black', activebackground='gray52')
menu_cfgrs = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=0, background='black', foreground='white', activeforeground='black', activebackground='gray52')
menu_hlp = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=0, background='black', foreground='white', activeforeground='black', activebackground='gray52')
menu_nts = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=0, background='black', foreground='white', activeforeground='black', activebackground='gray52')
# AGREGO LAS CASCADAS
menu.add_cascade(label="Archivo", menu=menu_archivo)
menu.add_cascade(label="Variables de entorno", menu=menu_var)
menu.add_cascade(label="Diseño Conceptual", menu=menu_dsg)
# AGREGO SUBMENUS A "ARCHIVO"
menu_archivo.add_command(label="Abrir")
menu_archivo.add_command(label="Guardar")
menu_archivo.add_command(label="Cerrar")
menu_archivo.add_separator()
menu_archivo.add_command(label="Salir", command=root.destroy)
# AGREGO SUBMENUS A "VARIABLES DE ENTORNO"
menu_var.add_command(label="Tabla ISA")
menu_var.add_command(label="NACA")
menu_var.add_command(label="Reynolds")
# AGREGO SUBMENUS "VARIABLES DE ENTORNO > COHEFICIENTES"
menu_coheficientes = tk.Menu(menu_archivo, tearoff=0, background='black', foreground='white', activeforeground='black', activebackground='gray52')
menu_coheficientes.add_command(label="Sustentacion")
menu_coheficientes.add_command(label="Resistencia")
menu_coheficientes.add_command(label="Viscocidad")
menu_coheficientes.add_command(label="Rozamiento")
menu_coheficientes.add_command(label="Densidad")
menu_coheficientes.add_command(label="Viscocidad")
# AGREGO SUBMENUS A "VARIABLES DE ENTORNO"
menu_var.add_cascade(label="Coheficientes", menu=menu_coheficientes)
menu_var.add_command(label="Establecer Condicion")
# AGREGO SUBMENUS A "DISEÑO CONCEPTUAL"
menu_dsg.add_command(label="Por criterio de diseño")
menu_dsg.add_command(label="Libre diseño")
menu_dsg.add_command(label="Instrucciones", command=inst)
# Se muestra la barra de menú en la ventana principal
root.config(menu=menu)
# Bucle de ejecución del programa
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Es un ejercicio para la universidad o es un programa para algun cliente?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki, Nono. Es para mi.